# How to implement Periscope's heart animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, cocos2d-iphone

I want to implement something similar like what periscope does to their live streaming app. To be specific, the countless floating heart emitted when user touch the screen. Is this could easily be achieved by SpriteKit or Cocos2D? Can anyone shed me some lights or , at least, a good starting point.

THANKS

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This can be achieved through `SKEmitterNode`

```
import SpriteKit

let heartsFile = "heart-bubbles.sks"//particle file

class HeartBubblesScene : SKScene {
 var emitter: SKEmitterNode?
 func beginBubbling() {

  emitter = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: heartsFile)

    let x = floor(size.width / 2.0)
    let y = heartHeight

    emitter!.position = CGPointMake(x, y)

    emitter!.name = "heart-bubbles"
    emitter!.targetNode = self

    emitter?.numParticlesToEmit = 1

    addChild(emitter!)

    emitter?.resetSimulation()
 }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var heartBubblesView: SKView!//Create a custom view inside view controller and set the class to SKView

let heartBubblesScene = HeartBubblesScene()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    heartBubblesView.presentScene(heartBubblesScene)
 }

 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    heartBubblesScene.beginBubbling()

 }

}
```

Here is an example [HeartAnimation](https://github.com/itsarjun/HeartAnimation.git)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11054290)

Comment: Hope it helps now! @BartłomiejSemańczyk

Comment: Thank @Aark so much!